# angular app TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, slice

I'm trying to learn angularjs. I use filter function to order some items like this:

```
angular.module('reverseDirective', [])
.filter('reverse', function() {
    return function(items) {
        return items.slice().reverse();
    }
});
```

When I put this to html file

```
<div class="panel-body" ng-repeat="each in story.stories | reverse">
                    <p>{{ each.content }}</p>
```

The console always show this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
    at http:localhost:3000/app/directives/reverse.js:6:15
    at fn (eval at <anonymous> (http:localhost:3000/js/angular.min.js:212:83), <anonymous>:4:203)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http:localhost:3000/js/angular.min.js:117:376)
    at n.$get.n.$digest (http:localhost:3000/js/angular.min.js:132:124)
    at n.$get.n.$apply (http:localhost:3000/js/angular.min.js:135:269)
    at l (http:localhost:3000/js/angular.min.js:87:152)
    at F (http:localhost:3000/js/angular.min.js:91:187)
    at XMLHttpRequest.K.onload (http:localhost:3000/js/angular.min.js:92:220)
```

I searched and tried, but still cant find a solution, so I'm waiting.

Comment: have you put a break point on your filter to see what items is?

Comment: I don't think you need a debugger to learn it's `undefined`. Why it's undefined you have to examine your controller and make sure that `$scope.story.stories` is defined properly. And second, filters should be error-proof against such stuff, so a check is required

Answer (score 2):

You should check if the items exist or not. This solution should work for you.

```
angular.module('reverseDirective', [])
       .filter('reverse', function() {
           return function(items) {
               if (!items) {
                   return;
               }
               return items.slice().reverse();
           }
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use angulars built in filter orderBy. You can pass it a function if needed. Check the docs  http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:orderBy . And it also supports reverse functionality.